# How to boot Android with flight mode (airplane mode) activated

Tags: wi-fi, custom-roms, nandroid, airplane-mode

Is it possible to boot up Android so flight mode is activated?

When I set airplane mode before rebooting or creating a nandroid backup the setting will stick.

Are there any files like init.d that are easy to modify where these kinds of boot options are stored?
Another alternative would be a modified Custom Recovery. But I haven't heard of one.

*Use case:*
*Restore an old Nandroid Backup, but before the system fetches all the updates (messenger...) the user wants to restore certain app data so nothing gets lost.*

That is only possible when in flight mode.

Answer (score 1):

An indirect possibility would be using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which has the capability of performing actions "on device start" (amongst many others). So you could setup a profile that says: "on device start" → "set airplane mode on". Other [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps like [llama](/questions/tagged/llama) might have the same capability.

Note however that the action can of course only be executed as soon as the app (Tasker/ Llama) is started, so there might be a delay in which airplane mode is turned off (and a network connection available). If you need to safely rule that out: take out the SIM card, and delete the AP config for your WiFi. That way the device would still boot with airplane mode disabled – but had no chance to connect anywhere. Third option would be booting it while inside a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) (or a lead box) …

Comment: the idea isn't bad but not universal at all. you have to plan that plus have to live with the fact that EVERY reboot means flught mode. i'm looking for an 'emergancy' helper. something that works afterwards, you know? thank you.

Comment: Removing SIM works always. And in case of emergency, switch off the WiFi *router*. Alternatively: where do those data backups come from? In case of ADB: have you tried `adb restore` when in recovery mode? I haven't tried, so I can't tell if that would work.

Comment: @Izzy: ADB only works in Android, the same way as fastboot only works in the bootloader.

Comment: @JoshHolland Not true, depends on your recovery. ADB *does* work in most custom recoveries (you can at least `adb shell` to them, and – sometimes after manual mounting – `adb push` and `adb pull`). I'm just not sure about `adb backup` and `adb restore`, as that involves the package manager as well which might not be available from recovery for some reason (especially with some partions possibly not mounted).

Comment: @Izzy Ahh, hadn't tried with custom recovery.

Comment: Thought so :) But, adding a single word to your previous comment, it still might be (sadly) true: `adb backup` as well as `adb restore` probably won't work, as both commands require interaction to approve the process on the device ("now unlock your …"). Would be interesting in fact to try that: "press vol-down to approve or vol-up to cancel"? Or, similar to flashing, a list of "No" with a single "yes" to select from? And how to enter the encryption pwd, if any? Morse with power-key? ;) As said: worth a try. There might even be a build.prop tweak you could setup from recovery...